# Show div on text entry

Tags: jquery

I have a form and I'd like to show a div based on the entered text in a text field. The script I'm using works just fine on my latest version of chrome but it doesn't work on IE or any of my members browswers. What they heck is wrong with the script?

```
    <script>
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#gname').change(function() {
($(this).val() == "NBA 2k10") ? 
$('#number').slideDown('fast') : $('#number').hide();
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: Might have something to do with how IE fires the change event.

Comment: Do you have the !DOCTYPE declaration in your html? IE will not interpret the code correctly if !DOCTYPE is missing.

Comment: doc type is there, I can't figure this out

Comment: FYI - In your code example above, there's an unmatched `(` before `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @patrick - Look closer, it's a side-effect conditional :)

Comment: @Nick - Ah, yes, looking closer... always a good idea. I should do it more! :o)

Answer (score 2):

`$("document")` isn't a valid selector in other browsers, you need `$(document)`, like this overall:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#gname').keyup(function() { //probably want keyup instead of change here
    if ($(this).val() == "NBA 2k10") 
      $('#number').slideDown('fast')
    else 
      $('#number').hide();
  });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/j3DpC/).

`$(document).ready(function(){` can also just be `$(function(){`.  `$("document")` doesn't work because it's looking for `<document>` element, which doesn't exist.

The `if`/`else` change is just to make it a bit cleaner overall, it's somewhat preference, but generally speaking your conditional statements shouldn't have side effects, that's not their intention.  You *can* use them that way, but it's better to be explicit, at least in my opinion.

Comment: @John - I added a demo to show it in action, that you probably *want* is the `keyup` event instead of `change` (which won't fire until you leave the textbox).  That's probably your current issue, that the `change` event doesn't fire when you think it does :)

Comment: Keyup, worked. beautiful. Let me know what your Goodiiz.com member id is please I'll send you 3 goodiiz chips for helping me out.

Comment: @John - I don't use it, but thanks :) Just be sure to accept answers if they resolve your issue, it'll help you get better/faster answers in the future :)

Comment: Nick - jQuery doesn't seem to mind having `document` in quotes when used with `ready()`. Works in Firefox, Safari, IE7 & IE8. Just thought I'd mention it. :o)

Comment: @patrick -  Hah I never noticed, actually it doesn't matter what the selector is at all: `$("ImNotARealElement").ready(function() { alert('hi'); });`, good catch.

Comment: Nick - Wow. No kidding. You can even have an empty object. Makes sense I guess since it's just setting the code aside until the `body` is loaded.

Comment: Sorry to clutter your answer with more of this, but just wanted to say that in the interest of not creating unnecessary jQuery objects, perhaps it is better to call `$.fn.ready(func...)` instead of the common versions. And +1 since it looks like you're not getting your Accept tonight. :o)

Comment: @patrick - Thanks :)  I think the `$(function)` version is fine for this as well, it's what I always use, and it's a direct shortcut without the extra wrapper object: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L159

Answer (score 0):

It probably fires in IE only after the input has lost focus. If you want to detect text change (cross-browser) before the focus on the input is lost, try keyup or keypress.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#gname').keypress(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "NBA 2k10") 
      $('#number').slideDown('fast')
    else 
      $('#number').hide();
  });
});
```