# Too many Database Calls

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have an auto refresh script that refreshes a page every 3 seconds. The page it refreshes ha few database queries. When I get 20 or more members on my site the server crashes because of all the calls to the database. Is there another way to check for changes in the database?

```
//Can't Chat
$strFind="SELECT * FROM cantchat";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$id=$row['memid'];

$strsql="DELETE FROM cometchat_chatroommessages WHERE userid=\"$id\"";
$chkrow1=mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());

}


if($banned<1){
$strFind="SELECT * FROM ttourmember WHERE memberid=\"$curmemid\"";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$membername=$row['membername'];
$console=$row['system'];

# timeout - how long should it take before visitors are no longer 'online'? (in     minutes)
define ('timeout', 20);
// check if visitor is already in the table
$lastactive =time();
$strFind="SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM online WHERE `memberid`=\"$curmemid\"";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$imonline=$row['total'];

if ($imonline<1) {
// Insert new visitor
$strsql="INSERT INTO    online(lastactive,memberid,membername,console,ipaddress,accountactive)   VALUES(\"$lastactive\",\"$curmemid\",\"$membername\",\"$console\",\"$ip\",'Y')";
$chkrow1=mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
$onlineid=mysql_insert_id();//copied        
} else {
// Update exisiting visitor
$strsql="UPDATE online SET     `lastactive`=\"$lastactive\",membername=\"$membername\",console=\"$console\",ipaddress=\"$i  p\" WHERE `memberid`=\"$curmemid\"";
mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
$chkrow5=mysql_affected_rows($connect);

$strsql="UPDATE ttourmember SET `ipadd`=\"$ip\" WHERE `memberid`=\"$curmemid\"";
mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
$chkrow5=mysql_affected_rows($connect);

}

// Remove any inactive visitors
$inactive = time()-21;

//Who's Online list
$strFind="SELECT * FROM online WHERE lastactive< $inactive AND `stay`<>'Y'";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$friendid=$row['memberid'].",";

$strsql="DELETE FROM friends WHERE toid=\"$friendid\" OR fromid=\"$friendid\"";
$chkrow1=mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());

}

$strsql="DELETE FROM online WHERE lastactive < $inactive AND stay<>'Y'";
mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
$chkrow5=mysql_affected_rows($connect);

//Can Chat
$query_chat = "SELECT * FROM online WHERE `memberid`<>\"$curmemid\" ORDER BY membername     DESC";
$chat = mysql_query($query_chat) or die(mysql_error());
$row_chat = mysql_fetch_assoc($chat);
$totalRows_chat = mysql_num_rows($chat);


//Count Pending Games
$strFind="SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tgamertournament WHERE `memberid` =     \"$curmemid\" AND `pending`='Y'";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$tpgames=$row['total'];

$strFind="SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tgamertournament WHERE `targetto` =   \"$curmemid\" AND `pending`='Y'";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$topgames=$row['total'];

$pgames=$tpgames+$topgames;

//Steam Received Sent Challenge 
$query_stgames = "SELECT * FROM tgtournamentrequest WHERE `gamer`=\"$curmemid\" AND  `active`<>'D' AND `scored`<>'Y' AND `type`='S' AND `startfteam`='Y' AND `isaccepted`='N'    AND `startsteam`='N' ORDER BY tournamentid DESC LIMIT 3";
$stgames = mysql_query($query_stgames) or die(mysql_error());
$row_stgames = mysql_fetch_assoc($stgames);
$totalRows_stgames = mysql_num_rows($stgames);

//Waiting For Fteam Sent Challenge To Get Accepted
$query_wftgames = "SELECT * FROM tgtournamentrequest WHERE `fteam`=\"$curmemid\" AND `active`<>'D' AND `scored`<>'Y' AND `type`='S' AND `startfteam`='Y' AND `isaccepted`='N' AND `startsteam`='N' ORDER BY tournamentid DESC LIMIT 3";
$wftgames = mysql_query($query_wftgames) or die(mysql_error());
$row_wftgames = mysql_fetch_assoc($wftgames);
$totalRows_wftgames = mysql_num_rows($wftgames);

//List Posted Pending Games Accepted
$query_apostedgames = "SELECT * FROM tgtournamentrequest WHERE `gamer` = \"$curmemid\"        OR `fteam`=\"$curmemid\" AND `active`<>'D' AND `scored`<>'Y' AND `type`='P' ORDER BY     tournamentid DESC LIMIT 3";
$apostedgames = mysql_query($query_apostedgames) or die(mysql_error());
$row_apostedgames = mysql_fetch_assoc($apostedgames);
$totalRows_apostedgames = mysql_num_rows($apostedgames);

 //List Posted Pending Games
$query_postedgames = "SELECT * FROM tgtournamentrequest WHERE `gamer` = \"$curmemid\"   OR `fteam`=\"$curmemid\" AND `active`<>'D' AND `scored`<>'Y' AND `type`='P' ORDER BY   tournamentid DESC LIMIT 3";
$postedgames = mysql_query($query_postedgames) or die(mysql_error());
$row_postedgames = mysql_fetch_assoc($postedgames);
$totalRows_postedgames = mysql_num_rows($postedgames);

//Report Score
$query_score = "SELECT * FROM tgtournamentrequest WHERE `fteam` = \"$curmemid\" AND    `gamer`<>'0' AND `isaccepted`='Y' AND `active`='Y' AND `startfteam`='Y' AND  `startsteam`='Y' AND `scored` <>'Y' ORDER BY tournamentid DESC LIMIT 3";
$score = mysql_query($query_score) or die(mysql_error());
$row_score = mysql_fetch_assoc($score);
$totalRows_score = mysql_num_rows($score);

//Steam Pending Score
$query_pscore = "SELECT * FROM tgtournamentrequest WHERE `gamer` = \"$curmemid\" AND   `fteam`<>'0' AND `active`='Y' AND `startfteam`='Y' AND `startsteam`='Y' AND scored <>'Y' ORDER BY tournamentid DESC LIMIT 3";
$pscore = mysql_query($query_pscore) or die(mysql_error());
$row_pscore = mysql_fetch_assoc($pscore);
$totalRows_pscore = mysql_num_rows($pscore);

//Delete Games
$query_dmoline = "SELECT * FROM tgamertournament WHERE `memberid` = \"$curmemid\" AND `deleted`<>'Y' AND `scored`<>'Y' AND `accepted` <>'Y' AND `targetto`='0' AND `isactive`='Y'";
$dmoline = mysql_query($query_dmoline) or die(mysql_error());
$row_dmoline = mysql_fetch_assoc($dmoline);
$totalRows_dmoline = mysql_num_rows($dmoline);
```

Comment: Wow, how long does it take for each query to run?

Comment: You know what, I have NO Idea

Comment: What does the query & table structure look like?

Comment: @Rob, You can imagine some answers are like yours. Would you like for me to accept that? The answers I've accepted are the ones that solved my questions, or would you like me to cheat this service.

Comment: can you post those database queries , so I can say that how to get that changes..

Comment: Even so... the server shouldn't crash. Are you managing all your database connections correctly?

Comment: @maulik just updated the post with the queries.

Comment: @John Sims The first question I looked at had an answer that you commented as correct but did not accept (even offered them some goodiz): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242858/show-div-on-text-entry/3242869#3242869

Comment: @Rob come on bro you really going to bicker with me? Show me the check mark next to the comment and I'll gladly accept it. It doesn't have a check mark next to it that's why I voted it as a great comment.

Comment: @Rob you are 100% correct. I'll do as you suggested from here on out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is there another way to check for changes in the database?`

Try `show processlist` in phpMyAdmin or a mysql-shell while your site is "under attack"... you should see the running queries and how long they are running. Maybe you find some heavy queries.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all I wouldn't do the following:

```
$strFind="SELECT * FROM online WHERE lastactive< $inactive AND `stay`<>'Y'";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$friendid=$row['memberid'].",";

$strsql="DELETE FROM friends WHERE toid=\"$friendid\" OR fromid=\"$friendid\"";
//echo $strsql;
//exit;
$chkrow1=mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Instead grab all the id's and delete them at once. I'd also only fetch the one column I need to do this:

```
$strFind="SELECT memberid FROM online WHERE lastactive< $inactive AND `stay`<>'Y'";
$result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
$offline = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $offline[]="'{$row['memberid']}'";
}
$friendids = implode(',', $offline);

$strsql="DELETE FROM friends WHERE toid IN ($friendids) OR fromid IN ($friendids)";
$chkrow1=mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You are right, but I think the real problem lies much deeper... "FROM online WHERE lastactive < $inactive" sounds not to become a large result set... in most times there should be no row because that query is fired about 10 or more times per second ^^

Comment: True, but its the only craziness i saw per se. Its hard to tell without a schema dump so we know the indexes and the table engine.

Comment: Also if hes got 20 concurrent connections polling the server ever 3 seconds and hes running under mod_php that could be part of the issue if its the server crashing and not just the db... Keep alive might need to be adjusted amongst other things...

Comment: hmm... `server crashing` what exactly does it means?
lets see if we'll get enough information. the current discussion seems to be about "how to use stack overflow"...